# How to simplify and generalise global data for cartography?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, generalization

I have a TIFF that shows biodiversity and I want to create a nicely looking cartography output. The data look like this
[image: Biodiversity]

If you can observe there are a lot of 'dots' and things can get a bit messy especially close to the boundaries of different zones. What do you recommend to get a much simpler version?
I converted it to a vector and tried several simplification algorithm runs, but although it gets better, I had to run it for 10 times to get something better but still it is not very good.

How can I derive something like this for example?

[image]

Comment: The ArcGIS Spatial Analyst tool has a majority filter tool that will help clean up messy data like your first picture.  Of course, you are making up data at that point.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/majority-filter.htm

Comment: Once it's converted to vector you can simply select and delete any polygons with an area smaller than (some threshold value). That will remove the "noisy" small outlier dots. You may need to also remove interior rings smaller than the same threshold area value.